# Remove duplicate items from lists in Python lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate items from lists in sublists on Python.

**Exemple :**

- myList = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,3], [7,8,9], [0,2,4]]

to

- myList = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [0]]

**I tried with this code :**

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,3],[7,8,9], [0,2,4]]
 
nbr = []

for x in myList:
    for i in x:     
        if i not in nbr:
            nbr.append(i)
        else:
            x.remove(i)
```

But some duplicate items are not deleted.

Like this : `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [0, 4]]`

I still have the number 4 that repeats.

Comment: try not to modify a list you are also iterating over, try `for i in x.copy():`

Comment: as @Matiss said. you are basically iterating over an actual list. Use copy() to iterate over a copy of list and delete from actual.  Add print() before append & remove to actually see the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You iterate over a list that you are also modifying:

```py
...
    for i in x:
        ...
        x.remove(i)
```

That means that it may skip an element on next iteration.

The solution is to create a shallow copy of the list and iterate over that while modifying the original list:

```py
...
    for i in x.copy():
        ...
        x.remove(i)
```

Comment: I literally just ended debugging on the OP's code, I was going to give the same explaination so a +1 is due

Answer (score 5):

You can make this much faster by:

1. Using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for repeated membership testing instead of a list, and
2. Rebuilding each sublist rather than repeatedly calling `list.remove()` (a linear-time operation, each time) in a loop.

```py
seen = set()

for i, sublist in enumerate(myList):
    new_list = []

    for x in sublist:
        if x not in seen:
            seen.add(x)
            new_list.append(x)

    myList[i] = new_list
```

```py
>>> print(myList)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [0]]
```

If you want mild speed gains and moderate readability loss, you can also write this as:

```py
seen = set()

for i, sublist in enumerate(myList):
    myList[i] = [x for x in sublist if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
```

Comment: The two points perfectly explain why this should be the way to go. It might be good though to show how this would be done without the `x in seen or seen.add(x)` 'trick'.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Added, thanks for the feedback. I haven't measured the performance, but it's probably almost the same, so not much reason to use the trick. The new version is also about 10x clearer, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Why you got wrong answer: In your code, after scanning the first 3 sublists, `nbr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Now `x = [0, 2, 4]`. Duplicate is detected when `i = x[1]`, so `x = [0, 4]`. Now `i` move to `x[2]` which stops the for loop.

Optimization has been proposed in other answers. Generally, 'list' is only good for retrieving element and appending/removing at the rear.